# query cassandra table with timestamp range without using allow filtering

Tags: python, cassandra

I want to add secondary index of type `timestamp`, in order to be able to query by timestamp range without 'ALLOW FILTERING'.
I can't use timeuuid, because the timestamp is different than now(). I have datetime which I should convert into timestamp.

I want to query by time, for example:
`session.execute("SELECT id from my_table WHERE date>'2019-09-01' AND date<'2019-09-04'")`.

Any suggestions of what is the right way of doing it? or how can I use timuuid from python with an input of the datetime? (convert datetime to uuid field)

Thanks.

```py
my_table = session.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_keyspace.my_table
                            (id text,
                            date timestamp,
                            PRIMARY KEY (id) 
                            )""")

session.execute("CREATE INDEX time_idx ON my_keyspace.my_table (date)""")
```

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I see a table in Cassandra with a single primary key on a nigh-unique column (ex: `PRIMARY KEY (id)`) I foresee problems like this happening.  You're right about how adding secondary indexes is definitely an anti-pattern.  My question to these designs is "Do you ever query by `id`?"  Because if you don't it shouldn't be the sole primary key.

I would definitely partition your table on something else.  **Essentially, data that you want to query together, you also want to *store* together.**

Let's say that for your use case you really only care about data for the last month.  Of course, this also assumes that a month's worth of data on a single partition doesn't violate Cassandra's limitation of 2 billion cells per partition.  But it'll make for a good example, so I'd build your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE data_by_month (
    id TEXT,
    date TIMESTAMP,
    month_bucket INT,
    value1 TEXT,
    value2 TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((month_bucket),date,id));
```

This is a modeling technique called "time bucketing."  In storing all data for each month in the same "bucket," I can now run queries like this:

```
aaron@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * from data_by_month
    WHERE date>'2019-09-01' AND date<'2019-09-04' AND month_bucket=201909 ;

 month_bucket | date                            | id | value1 | value2
--------------+---------------------------------+----+--------+--------
       201909 | 2019-09-02 23:21:00.000000+0000 | 4d |    456 |    abc
       201909 | 2019-09-03 12:34:00.000000+0000 | 1a |    123 |    abc

(2 rows)
```

Comment: if it constantly writing the data for current month, then he'll have hot partitions, and may not able to scale horizontally...

Comment: @AlexOtt exactly, which is why they need to pick a bucket that works with their access pattern and business logic.